# openapitools generating models with versions

Tags: android, gradle, openapi

I am trying to generate models for different version  , I tried forEach but it just generate for the last item , and I don't understand how pass type param

```
def goldGdsYamlVersions = ["v1", "v2"]
    task generateApiModels(type: org.openapitools.generator.gradle.plugin.tasks.GenerateTask) {
       goldGdsYamlVersions.forEach()  { APIVersion ->
    
        def goldGdsYamlFile = "$rootDir/gold-gds-${APIVersion}.yaml"
    
        generatorName = "kotlin"
        inputSpec = goldGdsYamlFile
        outputDir = "$buildDir/generated".toString()
        modelPackage = "com.goldholding.gold.data.model.$APIVersion"
    
        enablePostProcessFile = true
        skipOverwrite = false
        configOptions = [
                collectionType      : "list",
                serializationLibrary: "gson"
        ]
        systemProperties = [
                modelDocs: "false",
                models   : ""
        ]
    }}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
swaggerYamlVersions.forEach { APIVersionX ->
    tasks.create("$openApiGenerate$APIVersionX", org.openapitools.generator.gradle.plugin.tasks.GenerateTask.class, {
        def goldenGdsYamlFile = "$rootDir/golden-gds-${APIVersionX}.yaml"

        generatorName = "kotlin"
        inputSpec = goldenGdsYamlFile
        outputDir = "$buildDir/generated".toString()
        modelPackage = "com.goldenholding.golden.data.model.$APIVersionX"

        enablePostProcessFile = true
        skipOverwrite = false
        configOptions = [
                collectionType      : "list",
                serializationLibrary: "gson"
        ]
        systemProperties = [
                modelDocs: "false",
                models   : ""
        ]
    })

}

task openApiGenerates {
    swaggerYamlVersions.forEach{APIVersionX ->
        dependsOn("$openApiGenerate$APIVersionX")
    }
}
```